# Python question on join function getting different output

Tags: python, list

Why am I seeing this output while running this code:

```
list = []
for i in range(4):
    l = int(input())
    list.append(l)
    
    
print(str(list))
print("+".join(str(list)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[+1+,+ +2+,+ +3+,+ +4+]
```

Expected = `[1+2+3+4]`

Please correct my syntax

Comment: I hope we were helpful! If one of our answers solved your issue, please consider clicking the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `split(",")` and `"+".join()`.Also use `.strip` to remove the blank space.
Try this below:

```
print("+".join(map(str.strip, str(list).split(","))))
```

Result:

```
[1+2+3+4]
```

Answer (score 1):

`separator.join(sequence)` inserts `separator` between each item in `sequence`; if `sequence` is a *string*, it simply sticks the separator in between every character of the string.

I think the root of your confusion is that you're converting the *list* into a string, when it seems like you really want to turn each *item* into a string (so that the list of strings can then be joined).

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_as_string = str(lst)
print(list_as_string)
=> "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

To make each item in the list a string, you can use a list comprehension. (List comprehensions are very useful Python tools for applying the same operation to each item in a sequence; if you haven't used them, check out this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-basics-list-comprehensions-631278f22c40).)

```py
list_of_strings = [str(i) for i in lst]
print(list_of_strings)
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

The result of that can be joined like you would expect (and you can add brackets).

```py
output = "[" + "+".join(list_of_strings) + "]"
print(output)
=> "[1+2+3+4]"
```

---

Alternatively, if for some reason you definitely want to convert the list to a string first, you can use the `string.replace(old, new)` method to simply replace every `", "` with `"+"`.

```py
print(list_as_string.replace(", ", "+"))
=> "[1+2+3+4]"
```

---

Also note that `list` in Python is the actual name of the `list` class and it is a bad habit to redefine it as an ordinary variable.